# Can't access info.plist in Swift 2 framework

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks

No matter what I do, I can't seem to access my Info.plist file in the root of my framework's folder. So far, my code looks like this:

```
    private var Config: NSDictionary {
    get {
        if let config = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Info", ofType: "plist") {
            return NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: config)!
        }
        return Dictionary<String, AnyObject>()
    }
}
```

This returns a null `Dictionary`, as the `if let config` statement doesn't pass. I have also tried:

```
    private var Config: NSDictionary {
    get {
        if let config = NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary {
            return NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: config as! String)!
        }
        return Dictionary<String, AnyObject>()
    }
}
```

This time, the `if let` statement passes, but is a blank `Dictionary` (0 key/value pairs).

I am using Xcode 7.2.1. Help an iOS newbie out! Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: open your xcode setting. Select Target->YourApp->Build Phase->Copy Bundle resources.  Now find your file, If does not exist the add the file by pressing '+' button.

Comment: Nope, still not working. I tried with both blocks of code, and doing that for both the main Framework project, and the tests project.

Comment: Solved! Check out my answer for details. Thanks for your help, @Gagan_iOS :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved!**

After doing a bit more research, I found that access plists, or resources in general for that matter, are different for Frameworks. So, I tried:

```
            if let config = NSBundle(identifier: "Smoo.Framework")?.infoDictionary {
            return NSDictionary(dictionary: config["Key"] as! NSDictionary)
        }
```

("Smoo.Framework" being the name of the bundle my required plist is in)

And that works! Case closed. :)